# Can't understand the OR used for base conversion

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I was looking for an easy way to print an integer from the register in a decimal format (Intel 8086, if that's of any significance) and found something which works perfectly. The problem is, I can't quite get how it works. So the code for an integer stored in AX is:

```
or AX,'00'

mov AH,02h
mov DL,AL
int 21H
```

Of course I know the purpose of the last three lines but what kind of wizardry is involved in the OR operation here such that it changes the number stored in a binary form to a printable ASCII character stored in AL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character '0' is 0x30, 0x30|5 is 0x35 ... the ascii for '5'. You could use addition, but presumably `or` is a cheaper instruction.

Comment: (`or` also has the advantage of doing the work on `ah` and `al` in one go, which wouldn't fly with `add`)

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean about doing the work on ah and al in one go, though> Since we're limited to printing one digit of an integer at once anyway, it seems the instruction could just very well be substitued with [ADD AL,48], right?

Comment: I mean that if you have one number in `AL` and another in `AH`, `or`ing `AX` with `0x3030` (`'00'`) will convert both at once. Doing the `add` on `AL` would work just as well, but might eat an extra cycle (don't know for sure), and will obviously only work on `AL`.

Comment: @mornfall, it doesn't matter if you use `or` or `add` because both can be used to acton on `ah` and `al` at the same time for this case. If you have i.E. 0x3030 in ax and you do `add ax, 0505h` it will yield the same result as oring it. In this case, adding would be wrong though, because `or`ensures that only the relevant bits are set.

Comment: @Devolus you are right, but with `add` there's the added risk that if `AL` is not actually a single-digit number, the addition will cause a carry into `AH` and ruin it.

Comment: @mornfall, good point, I haven't thought of that. :) However, in cases of incorrect data, the result will be undefined in both cases anyway.

Answer (score 3):

ASCII code for character '0' is 48, i.e. 00110000.
By OR-ing it with the number 0 to 9 (i.e 0000 to 1001),
you get ASCII codes for the corresponding characters (00110000 to 00111001) in AL.